# Tumblr: add pages to custom theme

Tags: content-management-system, themes, blogs, tumblr

I am creating a custom theme with HTML and want to create a navigation menu for my pages. I am not sure how to do this however.

I have tried to add:

```
{block:HasPages} {/block:HasPages}
```

and

```
{block:Pages} {/block:Pages}
```

but nothing appears.

Do I just have to hard code the links into the theme? Is there no way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must have one or more Custom Page(s)
2. Each Custom Page must have Show Link enabled
3. The code block to show links to the Custom Page(s) is as follows:

   ```
    {block:HasPages}
        {block:Pages}
            <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a>
        {/block:Pages}
    {/block:HasPages}
   ```

Code per the [Tumblr HTML Guide](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#navigation).